# Simple circuit to boost line-level audio

Tags: microcontroller, audio, amplifier, adc, gpio

I am looking for suggestions or pointers to a simple circuit that boosts line-level audio, so that it is strong enough to use with the ADC peripheral on my MCU.

I am aware and have seen many that use an op amp, but I am looking for something cheaper (but still simple), that does not introduce any other artefacts except amplitude boost.

I believe line-level audio is centered at ground and has about a 1.6v swing, where as my ADC input requires a swing of 3.3v

EDIT: My preference is to get this done with a few resistors and capacitors, if that is possible??

Comment: why is using an op-amp buffer too complicated? i think you will struggle to find a solution that is simpler than that.

Comment: Yes of course, an op amp is the simplest solution. I have edited my question to focus more on my desire to find the cheapest possible solution (that is still relatively simple). One that preferably uses a few resistors and capacitors if that is possible???

Comment: It is impossible to amplify a signal without an active component like an op amp or transistor.  I suppose that is not entirely correct - you can build a mag amp that amplifies with only transformers.  But the bottom line is that resistors and capacitors are not sufficient - you need a transistor or an op amp.

Comment: alex.forencich - so this one isn't going to serve the purpose I require - http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-FhUsdrNu0lg/UMlVbCRLAVI/AAAAAAAAAJo/5L6IFgIIyps/s1600/schematic.png

Comment: @Remixed123 as the page that schematic came from says: `In order to get the Launchpad to be able to read line level audio, it is necessary to add a DC bias to the audio signal. ... I use a simple circuit (a capacitor and two resistors) to get the signal centered at 1.65 V with a 1.6 V swing.` That is not an amplifier, that's just dc biasing. If the signal is too weak, biasing will not provide much help. You asked for a boost, not just biasing.

Comment: Got and thanks. So I can try and use that circuit I linked to, but would be better off using an op amp or NPN to ensure I am receiving a strong enough signal

Comment: Actually, I would use a combination of the two.  Build the NPN transistor circuit below, then add a voltage divider after the output DC blocking cap to shift the DC component to 2.5 volts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An op-amp would be the best choice. Simpler than that is a single transistor pre-amp.

[image]

Should be powered by the same input range you need, and it will be biased Vin/2.

Alternatively, you can move R1 after the input dc-blocking cap C1, and lose C2.

[image]

Comment: An NPN should be cheaper than an op amp, but I am sure there must be a way to do this with just a few resistors and capacitors, making the solution very cheap and simple (though not as simple as an op amp or transistor solution)

Comment: @Remixed123 you mean you need less than 1 npn, 3 resistors and 1 cap?

Comment: Not so much a need, I will use what ever provides the cheapest solution and still performs the task required. I just feel that it is possible to do without the transistor....but haven't been able to work out how.

Comment: @Remixed123 It is not possible to amplify a signal with just resistors and capacitors.  It is mathematically provable.